# Is it possible to build an only html+css3 tab feature using Basscss v8.0.1?

Tags: html, css

I have this idea where I could really use a tab feature in my website.

Something like this: [Pure CSS Tab](http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal) but I currently use BassCSS.

In this codepen link that I shared with you, to make a beautiful tab it only takes this code:

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");

$background: #9b59b6;
$tabs-base-color: #8e44ad;
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #fff; 
  background: $background;  
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 100px 10px; 
  span { 
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
}
.tabs {
  width: 650px;  
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
  li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 21px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: $tabs-base-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px; 
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in-out);
    &:hover {
      background: darken($tabs-base-color, 10);
    }
  }
  .tab-content{
    z-index: 2;
    display: none; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 25px;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    left: 0; 
    background: darken($tabs-base-color, 15);
  }
  //The Magic
  [id^="tab"]:checked + label { 
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 17px; 
    background: darken($tabs-base-color, 15); 
  }
  [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
    display: block;
  }
}
p.link {
  clear: both;
  margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
  a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background-color: darken($tabs-base-color, 15);
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);
    &:hover {
      background-color: darken($tabs-base-color, 20);
    }
  }
}
```

I want something like that but less elaborated, just functional. I want it to be really responsive and using the methods that are available on BassCSS if possible.

Could you please provide an example or a simple step-guide on how to accomplish this? I know basic CSS so I might be able to follow instructions on how to extend what's necessary from BassCSS methods. :)

Comment: CSS-only? Definetivelly! It's super-simple! With BassCSS? No idea, never heard of it.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow